# How to make query like in access but in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am more familiar creating queries in access than in vb.net combine with access database. My question is probably simple but i have no clue how to start. I have a form with a tab control. In the first tab control I have a datagridview that I like to search data I figure it out how to do it. But the part I am stuck is on tab 2 I have another data grid view table but I only want to see certain value. For example I want to filter everything that says the value database. How could I do that In access you simply create a query and in quotations you added the value that you wanted to filter by "database". How to do the similar using vb.net?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: what version of vb.net are you using?? 2012 or 2010

Comment: The query is same as in Ms Access.You need to include the query in double quotes " " and make use of Dataset to access the details

Comment: I am using 2010. I know the steps for creating a query but is not the same. In MS Access I used to tell it "value" take that value and give me everything I need then I would change the source code to the query. so the form could retrieve all the values because it was running the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're filtering the same data set, you may be better off using a DataView and using the RowFilter property. Rowfilter is very similar to a Select statement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter your results, you will need to create an SQL statement.

For Example:

`Dim yourstatement As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM yourquery WHERE yourcolumn = yourdatabasevalue")`

Comment: I did a different approach it work for my needs but I wish it was a simpler way doing than what I did. basically what I did was that I have a main form once the user sign ins a form shows their menu of what they want to do like insert a record find a record. I have a tab with two data grid view I wanted one data grid view to search and the other one to filter everything that said database. But I kind of had it working but not what I expected the first data grid view changes as well.

Comment: What I end up doing was creating a form and text box as soonest the form loaded the text box change to database but I hide it so people couldn't see it and then it showed everything with the keyword database I got it to work like that. Is not what I expected but at least is a working condition. Almost forgot I did it by creating a query. and on change text added that. Is kind like a trick I trick the program into searching that value like I wanted to.